# How to add columns array values as a new array in rows array as per given example?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Table.css';

export class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        columns: ['state 1', 'state 2', 'state 3', 'state 4', 'state 5','state 6'],
        emptyheader: [''],
        rows: [
          ['state 1'],
          ['state 2'],
          ['state 3'],
          ['state 4'],
          ['state 5'],
          ['state 6']
        ],
        newrows : [],

        selectedTeam: ''
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      // this.addColumn = this.addColumn.bind(this)
      // this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange() {}

    render() {
      const { rows, columns } = this.state;
      const displayRows = rows.map(row => [...row, ...new Array(columns.length - row.length)]);
      return (
        <div>
          <table align="center">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                {this.state.emptyheader.map((emptyheader, i) =>
                  <td >{emptyheader}</td>
                )}
                {this.state.columns.map((column, i) =>
                  <td >{column}</td>
                )}
              </tr>

              {displayRows.map((row, i) =>
                <tr key={i}>
                  {row.map((cell, i) =>
                    (i < 1) ? (
                      <td scope="row" key={i}>{cell}</td>
                    ) : (
                        <td>
                          <select>
                            <option value="forward">Forward</option>
                            <option value="reverse">Reverse</option>
                            <option value="NA">NA</option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                      )
                  )}
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <button onClick={this.handleChange}>add</button>

        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Table;
```

Comment: Can you please add some details to your question?.

Comment: i have a columns array. based on this array i want rows array. as u can see each value of columns array is an array in rows array. values present in rows array are hard coded. but i want to add these values on button click. how can i achieve this?